# How to set correct SES Identity Policy for a tomcat beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ses

I want to send emails from an tomcat beanstalk but I receive the following error message

*User 'arn:aws:sts::123:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-123' is not authorized to perform 'ses:SendEmail' on resource 'arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:123:identity/example.com'
(Service: Ses, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 2a82693d-3344-4b53-8c8c-ef347c23cd29, Extended Request ID: null)*

I have declared the following Identity Policy in SES Console on example.com

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmt1624645438239",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::123:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-123"
            },
            "Action": "ses:SendEmail",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:123:identity/example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

but still I got the the error message. Why?

Comment: Please format the code samples in your question.

Comment: Sorry for my format, this is my first question on stalk overflow I already spent some good hours to try to sent emails from an tomcat beanstalk. On localhost everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this is to create an policy from Identity and Access Management (IAM)

1. Go to Identity and Access Management (IAM) dashboard > Customer managed policies
2. Create policy for SES service (in the resource I gave access to all my ARNs)
3. Attach ec2 role